# How to set up the minimum limit of the imputated value in phylopars(), (RPhylopars package), in R

Tags: r, imputation

I am using phylopars() in Rphylopars package in R to generate the missing values in a large dataset about animal body traits (eg body size). (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rphylopars/versions/0.2.9/topics/phylopars) 
This method is called imputation and what it does is to phylogenetically estimate this missing datas.

However the output of the imputation contains some negative values which make no sense because all the estimated trait have to be bigger than zero. 
I wonder how I can fix this issue or how to set up a minimum limit for the estimated values.

I'm not new in R but new in Rphylopars so maybe that question is pretty naive but I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: you may want to try to send an email to the R SIG phylo mailing list for this type of question: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-phylo

Comment: many thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

For correlated traits, values from one trait will influence another trait resulting in potentially negative results. `phylopars` allows you to specify if traits are correlated, so you can try setting `phylo_correlated = FALSE` or imputing the traits individually.

Alternatively transforming can ensure the trait stays within range, depending on the nature of your data. [log transforming](http://www.biostathandbook.com/transformation.html) (and back) and assessing the distribution can help.